# Iterating a list VS using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large list called reassembly organized like this:

```
['HYDR', 30472.0, 'B'], ['HYDR', 30470.0, 'S'], ['HYDR', 30474.0, 'B'].....
```

A piece of my code:

```
sum_buys = 0
sum_sells = 0
for deal in reassembly:
    ticker, vol, oper = deal[0], deal[1], deal[2]
    if oper == "B":
        sum_buys = sum_buys + vol
    elif oper == "S":
        sum_sells = sum_sells + vol
```

List is very large. It takes about 5 minutes to run from start to end. Very long time.

Can pandas library help me to do it faster? I never worked with it.

What should i do?

1. Convert list called reassembly to pandas dataframe
2. Use pandas methods to count both parameters: sum_buys and sum_sells

Help me please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can and should convert the list into a pandas dataframe and use `groupby()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(reassembly, columns=['tickers','vol','operation'])

df.groupby('operation')['vol'].sum()
```

Output for the sample data:

```
operation
B    60946.0
S    30470.0
Name: vol, dtype: float64
```

Also, say, maybe you're interested in buy/sell total per ticker, you can do:

```
df.groupby(['tickers','operation'])['vol'].sum()
```

and get something like this:

```
tickers  operation
HYDR     B            60946.0
         S            30470.0
Name: vol, dtype: float64
```

To ignore deals with `vol<100000`, we can keep all deals with `vol >= 100000` by

```
df = df[df['vol']>=100000]
```

Comment: Thank you, dear friend! Let me ask you additional question: ignore deals if vol < 100000.

Comment: @DeepSpace see added details.